# Write two strings into one column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I want to write 2 strings into one column within an xlsx file using pandas like

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/ - release notes tab

where the part of the hyperlink is clickable. The '- release notes tab' should not part of the hyperlink. Something like in the screenshot.

[image: two strings one with url format]

I am trying something like this. The column I am trying to write is called 'Known Issues'. Please see the `if 'Known Issues' in df:` line.

```
def create_excel_with_format(headers,values,full_file_name_with_path):
   
   #Write to CSV in xlsx format with indentation.
   df = pd.DataFrame(data=values,columns=headers)
   #df = df.set_axis(df.index*2 + 1).reindex(range(len(df)*2)) #Create a blank row after every row.

   with pd.ExcelWriter(full_file_name_with_path) as writer:
        
        #For any list items inside of the excel file we remove the square brackets[]
        for index,row in df.iterrows():
            for col in list(df.columns):
                if isinstance(row[col], list):
                    row[col] = ", ".join(row[col])

        df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
        workbook  = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

        #Write the location each comma separated in new line if exists (For Nuget exists and thirdparty no).
        if 'Location' in df:
            df["Location"] = df["Location"].str.join("\n")
            twrap = workbook.add_format({"text_wrap": True})
            idx_location = df.columns.get_loc("Location")
            worksheet.set_column(idx_location, idx_location, 60, twrap)
        
        if 'Known Issues' in df:
            df["Known Issues"]=df["Known Issues"].str.join(" - release notes tab") #DOES NOT WORK
         
        header_format = workbook.add_format({
            'bold': True,
            'border': False,
            'text_wrap': False,
            'font_size':13})

        for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
            worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `#DOES NOT WORK`? Since it is not specified what is inside `df["Known Issues"]`, you cannot get a correct answer, only a guess. E.g. to use `df["Known Issues"] + "something"` instead of `join`

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite your function (but I do not test the code like you did not provide an example).

I think the problem is the location of your first `for` loop, because you get rid of of all lists items by turning them into strings before applying a `join` function... that requires a list to be provided.

Your approach should be to make all the `join` treatments you need **before** you get rid of remaining lists.

```py
def create_excel_with_format(headers,values,full_file_name_with_path):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=values,columns=headers)
    
    with pd.ExcelWriter(full_file_name_with_path) as writer:

        # Dataframe treatments first
        if 'Location' in df:
            df['Location'] = df['Location'].apply(lambda x: "\n".join(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x)
        if 'Known Issues' in df:
            df['Known Issues'] = df['Known Issues'].apply(lambda x: x + " - release notes tab" if pd.notnull(x) else x)
        # For any list items inside of the excel file we remove the square brackets[]
        df = df.applymap(lambda x: ", ".join(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x)

        # Excel treatments
        workbook  = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']    
        if 'Location' in df:
            twrap = workbook.add_format({"text_wrap": True})
            idx_location = df.columns.get_loc("Location")
            worksheet.set_column(idx_location, idx_location, 60, twrap)
        df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
        
        header_format = workbook.add_format({
            'bold': True,
            'border': False,
            'text_wrap': False,
            'font_size':13})
```